# Delphi 10.2 Android App - callback (JHandle) of JAR object

Tags: java, android, delphi

I have been struggling with callback and TJHandle for a couple of days with the Zebra 220 printer (I use their SDK).

I have this code:

```
TPrintCallback = class (TJavaLocal, JHandler_Callback)
function handleMessage (msg: JMessage): Boolean; cdecl;
end;

TfrmMain = class (TForm)
[..]
private
FCallback: TPrintCallback;
FHandler: JHandler;
end;
[...]
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate (Sender: TObject);
begin
FCallback: = TPrintCallback.Create;
FHandler: = TJHandler.JavaClass.init (FCallback);
FPrinter1: = TJMobilePrinter.JavaClass.Init (TAndroidHelper.Context,FHandler, TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
[...]
end;

function TPrintCallback.handleMessage (msg: JMessage): Boolean;
begin
Result: = True;
ShowMessage (msg.what.ToString + '' + msg.arg1.ToString);
end;
```

And the code generates this error: Project NextMobileApp.apk raised exception class EJNIFatal with message 'Invoke error: method' handleMessage 'not found'.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What are your "uses" clauses for this project? In what unit is TJMobilePrinter defined?

Comment: TJMobilePrinter is generated from a jar file. The Delphi module of this file is in the com.zebra.printer.pas module.

In w, I use a lot of modules. I can paste them here, but does it matter? com.zebra.printer.pas is also there.

Yesterday I had work with this until 4am and still do not know anything. I do not understand why Delphi can't see the handleMessage method.

Comment: I suspect you have coded this all wrong. Have you previously coded Android listener code in Delphi, like for example CONNECTIVITY_ACTION or ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED? That code would serve as a "prototype" for what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Does having an explicit public visibility specifier for the handleMessage method in TPrintCallback help?

Comment: TPrinterCallback is my type. I had code it on a pattern of JHandler_Callback. That's what I thought, that the problem is in visibility of the function. But whether I set PUBLIC or anything else I always get a message that the function was not found.
I can not find a example of using JHandle in Delphi.